# Como fechar o modal do bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Preciso fechar um *modal* ao clicar no `submit`.

Ele cadastra objetos via *JavaScript* e portanto, não faz *refresh* na página. Até aí, tudo bem. O problema é que o *modal* não fecha...

Eu fiz:

```
var janela = document.getElementById('cadastroCliente');
janela.remove();
```

Mas ao finalizar a operação, apesar de fechar o *modal*, a tela fica bloqueada...

Declaração do modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="cadastroCliente" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="cadastroClienteLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Tentei, também, assim:

```
janela.style.display = "none";
```

Sem sucesso... Ambos os comandos fecham o *modal*, porém não desbloqueia a tela de trás...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#cadastroCliente .close").click();
```

Basta chamar o botão fechar... Consegui resolver!